# facebook API add image along with wall feed

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, post

It is possible to post to a Facebook wall a message with image (not an image link, but image data)?

I did not find this possibility either in http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/ or in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/attachments/.

And I was ready to put up with impossibility of doing it, but I came across documentation for `SLComposeViewController` class introduced in iOS 6.0 (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/SLComposeViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

This class has a method `- (BOOL)addImage:(UIImage *)image` that does exactly what I need.

I program for Android and hence I cannot use it. But obviously this method must use facebook API. But I cannot find it: everything related to image posting requires url, not data.

So, is is possible in Android to post to a Facebook wall a message with image data?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#photos

Comment: By _image data_ you mean an image from the gallery or a camera, etc right? If yes, check the answer I am posting in a couple of minutes.

Comment: No, I mean an image that was created programmatically. For instance, by resizing existing image from assets folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I posted the answer almost with your comment. You can use something like this to cast you Image from `assets` into a `Bitmap`.

```
InputStream bitmap = null;

try {
    bitmap = getAssets().open("icon.png");
    bmpImageGallery = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bitmap);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    bitmap.close();
}
```

*This is how I display an Image from the Gallery via an Intent in the `onActivityResult` method:*

```
targetURI = data.getData();

try {

    bmpImageGallery = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), targetURI);

    // SET THE IMAGE FROM THE GALLERY TO THE IMAGEVIEW
    imgvwSelectedImage.setImageBitmap(bmpImageGallery);

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

*This is the code to upload the image:*

```
byte[] data = null;

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmpImageGallery.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
data = baos.toByteArray();

Bundle postImgGallery = new Bundle();

// ADD THE PHOTO DATA TO THE BUNDLE
postImgGallery.putByteArray("photo", data);

// ADD THE CAPTION FROM THE STRING finalStatusMessage TO THE BUNDLE
if (finalStatusMessage.equals(""))  {
    /*****  DO NOTHING HERE     *****/
} else {
    postImgGallery.putString("caption", finalStatusMessage);
}

Utility.mAsyncRunner.request(userID + "/photos", postImgGallery, "POST", new PhotoUploadListener(), null);
```

**NOTE:** In this bit here `"caption", finalStatusMessage`, the `caption` can also be substituted with `message`. I have never seen any difference in the posts using either of these. But do check before using either, just to be safe. ;-)

*This class is used to check the status of the upload:*

```
private class PhotoUploadListener extends BaseRequestListener   {

    @Override
    public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
        // DISPLAY A CONFIRMATION TOAST
    }

}
```